# Adding a UIView below the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a UIViewController added using addSubview hanging out on top of another UIViewController.  I would like the added view to hang out below the screen to be called up with a nice animation when I need it.

Is there a way to add a subview to a screen at a certain location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify its `.frame` property, e.g.

```
[self.view addSubview:theView];
CGRect newFrame = theView.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;
theView.frame = newFrame;
```